# Java 8 stream. Convert array to LinkedHashMap and continue work with entrySet in single stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I need to count the frequency of words in array. And handle result(I think it must be an entrySet )... An order of the entrySet is also important. So I suppose, that array must be converted to LinkedHashMap...

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(String word : words) {
        Integer count  = map.get(word);
        count = (count == null) ? 1: ++count;
        map.put(word, count);
}
```

I found next solution but the order is not respected.
And is it possible use that stream without collect operation(but with map or flatMap)?

```
Map<String, Long> collect = 
    wordsList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think this groupingBy collector should create a LinkedHashMap? Isn't there any other collector that groups by, but allows specifying the kind of Map to create? Have you read the javadoc of Collectors?

Comment: @JBnizet, as I understand groupingBy collector looks fine for my task but it don't create LinkedHashMap... i just ask how to make it to keep order...
and how to continue use same stream but with new converted items...

Comment: I understand that. My point is that if you just read the javadoc, you would be able to find the answer on your own. Reading documentation is the key to become an autonomous, productive programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're close but you'll need to use the [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector that takes 3 arguments like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Long> resultSet =
               wordsList.stream()
                        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                      LinkedHashMap::new, 
                                            counting()));
```

The second argument to the [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector being the supplier and in your case since you want a `LinkedHashMap` then that's what you'll need to provide as shown above.

Comment: Thank you! It's work. One more question. How to convert it without using collect?
I mean, after converting I'd like continue using this stream... e.g. for sorting by entry value... Should I create new stream from result map? Or there is some magic(e.g. map or flatMap)?

Comment: @A.Yam one solution I can think of for now is by using [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) collector to apply a finishing function after groupingBy and sort by value other than that you may need to create a new stream and sort by value.